# React Native: build Login Screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-fbsdk

I am just starting with react native and I want to know How do I build a login and singup form  shares same screen. Where both login and singup tabs shows on one screen. Just need to tap on any tab and the same form opens up to fill.
Please check the url of video below for reference what I am trying to achieve with React native
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HH2PmZUAhsgBa6iqyt4-uHVvZXIp30H3/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you've already tried in terms of code? Have you read React's docs to understand what a state is and how it affects the rendering process of a component? Are you planning on using redux as your state management or plain component states? It's really hard to get someone to help you without providing enough info.. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Hey thanks for the article. I am not using redux just plain component. To understand it better please watch the 5 sec video I've updated the gdrive link for the video above. Once Again thanks :-)

Comment: That is an easy method. But what have you tried, provide code snippets. You learn by trying and when getting stuck ask a question here.

Comment: @SGhaleb honestly I didn't start to write code for this yet. Last night I was reading all the docs of react native to get started and also found a UI kit component called react native elements where I found this login screen so I thought how can I also do the same but couldn't find any tutorial for that :'-(

Comment: I see, I would highly suggest starting the base for this, so you have a common understanding of what is going on. Install `react-native-elements` and put together the components and then ask for the functionality of the tabs.

Comment: @SGhaleb Thanks I'll do the same. But is it possible to build this screen without any UI kit components? And we developers call to this type of screen. :-)

Comment: Yes its possible, you just need 2 buttons, 2 child components and a function to swap between the components. But if you want the same UI as that, then you would need to look at their sourcecode and take the styles which will help you achieve this.

Comment: @SGhaleb Oh I understand. Thanks you save me :-p

Comment: No problem, try it and once you get stuck you can ask here. Because I think its very unlikely someone will do the whole thing here for you(for free) without you attempting .

Comment: @SGhaleb Yes, I can understand. That's why I just started with react native elements I'll ask it if I'll stuck in any problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm already designing this type of screen in my case, I manage state for changing form like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Image, ScrollView, UIManager, LayoutAnimation, BackHandler  } from 'react-native'
import styles from '../stylesheet/LoginSignup';
import SignupForm from '../components/SignupForm';
import SigninForm from '../components/SigninForm';

export default class Auth extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            IsOpenTab : 'SignIn',   //  'SignIn', 'SignUp' OR 'ResetPassword'
        };
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        // LayoutAnimation.spring();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }

    handleBackPress = () => {
        return false;
    };

    render() {

        return (

            <ScrollView style={styles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>

                <StatusBar backgroundColor='#2c8ba6' barStyle='light-content' />

                <View style={styles.TopLogoArea}>

                    <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/bg_top.png')} style={styles.TopLogoAreaBackground}>

                        <View style={{paddingTop: 20}}>

                            <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{width: 150, height: 150,}}/>

                        </View>

                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>



                                {
                                    this.state.IsOpenTab === 'SignIn' ? <View style={styles.TabArea}><View style={styles.TabActiveArea}><Text style={styles.TabActiveLable}>SIGN IN</Text><View style={styles.TabActiveLine}/></View></View> : <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.NavigateForm('SignIn')} activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.TabArea}><Text style={styles.TabDeactiveLable}>SIGN IN</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                                }



                            <View style={styles.TabArea}>

                                <Text style={{color:'#2dc7b0', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize: 12}}>OR</Text>

                            </View>



                                {
                                    this.state.IsOpenTab === 'SignUp' ? <View style={styles.TabArea}><View style={styles.TabActiveArea}><Text style={styles.TabActiveLable}>SIGN UP</Text><View style={styles.TabActiveLine}/></View></View> : <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.NavigateForm('SignUp')} activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.TabArea}><Text style={styles.TabDeactiveLable}>SIGN UP</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                                }



                        </View>

                    </ImageBackground>

                </View>

                <View style={{paddingVertical:40,}}>

                    {
                        this.state.IsOpenTab === 'SignIn' ? <SigninForm navigation={this.props.navigation} /> : <SignupForm  navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                    }

                </View>


            </ScrollView>

        );
    }

    NavigateForm = (method) => {

        const CustomLayoutLinear = {
            duration: 300,
            create: {
                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
                property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
            },
            update: {
                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
                property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
            },
        };
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutLinear );

        if(method === 'SignUp'){
            this.setState({
                IsOpenTab : 'SignUp',
            });
        }else{
            this.setState({
                IsOpenTab : 'SignIn',
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something as a flag in state,for example if you touch login the flags turns into true and if you touch singin the flag turns into false,and by this way you can show 2 screens